# .gitignore is not ignoring files even if it is untracked already

Tags: git, gitignore

I read a lot of similar articles but none of them actually solves the problem.
I have a .gitignore file that looks like this:

```
*.class 
 
.idea/ 
./a1-basic/build/ 
./a1-basic/.gradle/
```

I want to ignore the `build` folder and `.gradle` folder. And these two folders are not currently tracked by git.
[image]

However, when I run `git add .`, it still adds these two folders. I have tried the method found online to run `git rm -r --cached .`. But these folders are still added when I `git add .`.
Please advise what to do. Thank you

Comment: `./a1-basic/build/` is wrong; it should be `a1-basic/build/`. Similar for `./a1-basic/.gradle/`. As an aside, I prefer to create the `.gitignore` at the level of the things-to-be-ignored: if you create a `.gitignore` inside `a1-basic` it can contain `/.gradle/` and `/build/`. Confusingly, it needs to list them as `/.gradle/` etc rather than just `gradle/` to match the behavior you get from the top level `.gitignore`. I can go into detail if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You gitignore gradle folders like this.

```
# Gradle
.gradle/
build/
```